# Android layout: chat bubble with date text in bottom right and baseline of message text

Tags: android, xml, layout, chat

This question has been asked many times but never got a correct answer.

How can I build up a layout (that is similar to the most common messaging apps like Whatsapp, Telegram) with following characteristics:

- It has a view that acts as container and has a background with a image of a bubble.
- In the container there are two elements, a text message and the text date.
- The text message start from top left and can have multiple lines.
- The text date is aligned to the baseline of the last text message line, and on the right of it.

I've tried to reach it with relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/message_bubble_container"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_date_separator_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_message_background"
    android:padding="4dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:id="@+id/message_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            tools:text="This is a message long that causes the date to leave the screen!" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:id="@+id/message_time"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/message_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/message_text"
            android:textColor="@color/material_grey_900"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="18:58"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

It works good when the text message is on one single line, but when it grows to fill the width of the container, it pushes out the date from the screen. How can I avoid this behavior and make the text message keep a margin on the right for the date?

[image: One line]
[image: Multiple lines]

If this was CSS I was just needed to add a `margin-right: 40px;` to the `.message_text`. Of course this is Android and not CSS so...

Moreover, I dislike to use a `maxWidth` on the `@id/message_text` because I don't know how many dp will the screen be.

Lastly, I've heard some talking about `FlowLayout`. Is there a way?

Thanks to anyone will try to solve this problem that affects anyone that is tring to develop a chat layout.

Comment: Still no solution for this layout problem.

Comment: not yet? Interesting, how telegram and other apps do that

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear layout with vertical orientation instead of Relative layout. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/message_bubble_container"
android:layout_below="@+id/message_date_separator_container"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/chat_message_background"
android:padding="4dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        tools:text="This is a message long that causes the date to leave the screen!" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:id="@+id/message_time"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/message_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/message_text"
        android:textColor="@color/material_grey_900"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="18:58"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try, and let me know f it worked. :)

Comment: This move the date always under the message text, and not on the baseline of the bottom line. So, even if this is close, it is not what was request. This question seems really hard to have an answer!

Comment: Did you try to give negative marginTop. Works for me sometimes.

Comment: It can causes the message text to overlap the massage date, thank you anyway!

Comment: hey, have you tried using horizontal linear layout and give more weight to text(message). Then put gravity of other text(date) right | bottom

Answer (score 0):

take that date text view out of inner relative layout and keep that in parent relative layout with alignparentbottom true and align parentright true

Happy coding

Comment: This cause the bubble container to fill the entire width of the parent as a view in it as `alignParentRight="true"` . [Image](https://postimg.org/image/9ogr6y54l/). Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?